# How to force WAMP Ticket Authentication?

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn, wamp-protocol

I'm using the older [Autobahn|Python subclassing API](http://autobahn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wamp/programming.html#session-lifecycle) so that I can include ticket authentication for connecting to a WAMP bus. When I run all parts of the environment on my local machine, everything works fine and dandy - connection, challenge, authentication, publication of messages - but when I move over to my testing environment on an external server, the challenge for authentication doesn't seem to happen. My subclass looks like this:

```
class ClientSession(ApplicationSession):
    def onConnect(self):
        log("Session connected")
        self.join(self.config.realm, [u"ticket"], ROLE_ID)
    def onChallenge(self, challenge):
        log("Authentication challenged")
        if challenge.method == u"ticket":
            return TICKET
    @inlineCallbacks
    def onJoin(session, details):
        log("Connected to WAMP")
        while True:
            session.publish(u"topic", message)
            yield(60)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    RUNNER = ApplicationSession(url=WAMP_URL, realm=u"my-realm")
    RUNNER.run(ClientSession)
```

When I run the full application on my computer, it goes through all of the steps perfectly fine, but when I run it on my test server that has a slightly different configuration, the only output that is logged is from the `onConnect` method. I need the authentication to be able to publish messages. Help!

Comment: The guess with the fewest assumptions would be that something that differs between your computer and your external server makes a difference.  A related guess would be that the network differences between the two configurations makes a difference.  But it's pretty challenging to narrow it down further from there.  There are too many ways a computer or a network could be different from another.  I think solving your problem will hinge on reducing the differences between these configurations until they are similar enough that you can spot the remaining _important_ difference.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Thanks for the recommendation. I ran my local configuration on the dev server and discovered that I hadn't been updating the crossbar config file in the right path on the dev server, so it didn't have the correct principals. I guess it was just silently failing the challenge. I feel pretty dumb.

Comment: Glad you found the problem.  No reason to feel dumb.  There's really no such thing as a "simple explanation".  There's just an incredibly vast ocean of minutia, every last corner of which must have the right state for things to go right... It's pretty common for a corner or two to get overlooked for a while from time to time.